# Error No route matches [GET] "/root_path" in rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using Rails tutorial with example book by Michael Hartl as a reference for this question.

Here i am using rails 3.1.3  . What is the best way to use Named Routes

routes.rb

```
 root :to => "pages#home"
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact' 
  match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'      
  match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
```

When I access these routes from a view using about I find no error but when I am access it by "about_path"  I get an error. But in the book they use about_path. Have the concept of  named routes changed in rails 3.1 ?

```
        <li><%= link_to "About", '*about*' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", 'contact' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Home", 'root_path' %></li>
```

If i use "about_path" in the above code I get an error 'route not found'

Question 1. What is the best way to use named routes inside the views? (Best way means I only need to change the route path at single place )

Question 2. How can i access root with concept of named routes? 
(I get an error message when i try to access it using 'root_path').

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
JP:guard2 jayparteek$ rake routes
   root  /                  {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
contact  /contact(.:format) {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
  about  /about(.:format)   {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
   help  /help(.:format)    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
```

Accessing Named routes from views

```
    <li><%= link_to "About", 'about' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", 'contact' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "News-Home", '/' %></li>
```

Routes

```
  match '/contact' => 'pages#contact' 
  match '/about' => 'pages#about'      
  match '/help' => 'pages#help' 

  root :to => "pages#home"
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to omit the "'" arround ..._path, I think.

Comment: yeah right Aix, every new version of rails have different settings.

Comment: Helper methods have never been quoted.

Answer (score 3):

- make sure the root is first.
- at the command line type `rake routes` to see what routes and _path variables you have.
- remove the `:to`'s but leave ther hashrocket `=>`'s (EXCEPT for root! - leave the `:do` there)

Comment: Whats the named route for root ? if i use root_path it gives me an error "No route matches [GET] "/root""

Comment: if i use 'root'   i get error 'No route matches [GET] "/root"'

Answer (score 2):

(1) In routes.rb

**match '/about' => 'pages#about'**

will automatically create a variable *about_path* that stores your path name - Your path name, by the way, is distinct from your URL. The routing statement literally instructs rails that whenever someone types */about* as URL, rails is to take the action *about* as defined in the controller *pages*. In addition, that instruction is stored in shorthand in the implicit named route *about_path*, which rails creates by concatenating the method name *about* to the string *_path* without any intervention on your part.

(2) You will be using that variable in ... app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb

<%= link_to "About",    about_path  %>

and ditto in ... app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb

(3) In ... spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb, you will use

**describe "About page" do

   before { visit about_path }**

And yes, if you really understand routing, you understand 90% of the design of rails so make sure that you understand the contents of routes.rb inside out.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes from path variables, i.e. use this in the .erb file:

```
    <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
```

Comment: I found this to be the proper solution for the questions. Works great thanks User*